# .NET Task: How can I create a collection of tasks that can all be executed synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, task

In my application, I add a bunch of operations to a List(Of Task) like below:

```
Dim Tasks As New List(Of Task)

Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                                End Sub))

Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                                End Sub))

Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray())
```

When I call `Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray())`, it executes all tasks simultaneously as expected.  However, debugging/stepping through threaded methods is a bit difficult to do, so I'd like to be able to execute all of these synchronously (I'd create an AppSetting in my config file that I could use to determine whether or not to run the tasks synchronoulsy or asynchronously).  However, calling `.RunSynchronously()` on a Task that has been created using `.StartNew()` throws an exception.

How should I build this list of tasks so that I can toggle between synchronous and asynchronous execution?

**Edit:**  Conceptually, here is what I would like to do:

```
If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ExecuteAsynchronously") = "1" Then
    Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray())
Else
    Task.WaitAllAsynchronously(Tasks.ToArray())
End If
```

I know that `.WaitAllAsynchronously()` doesn't exist, but you can still see the end result of what I am trying to achieve.  If I have to create an extension method called `.WaitAllAsynchronously()` that iterates through each task an executes it synchronously then that's what I will do.

Since `.StartNew()` doesn't support sychronous execution, I need to build my list of tasks without actually starting them, but in a way that supports both synchronous and asynchronous execution.

Comment: Well instead of using TaskFactory and StartNew(), create a new Task. And use subs for the content of the Tasks for easy debug. I m not sure synchronous access is more easy to debug... I would rather unit test the subs called by the Tasks.

Comment: I just posted an answer.  I didn't want to steal your thunder there, but I've already tried that once before.  The problem was that I wasn't calling `.Start()` for each thread which I just discovered I needed to do.  Thanks for the comment, though.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Parallel.Invoke` and set it to use a single thread.

```
Dim po AS new ParallelOptions()
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1

Parallel.Invoke(po,
                Sub()
                   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                End Sub,
                Sub()
                   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                End Sub
                )
```

Comment: That's not synchronous, just sequential

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do what I want using Tasks.  I was going to just delete my question, but I felt others may benefit from this, so here is what I did:

```
Dim ExecuteSynchonously As Boolean = True

Dim Tasks As New List(Of Task)

Tasks.Add(New Task(Sub()
                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                   End Sub))

Tasks.Add(New Task(Sub()
                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                   End Sub))

'will create helper extension methods for these
If ExecuteSynchonously Then
    Tasks.ForEach(Sub(t)
                      t.RunSynchronously()
                  End Sub)
Else
    Tasks.ForEach(Sub(t)
                      t.Start()
                  End Sub)
    Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray)
End If
```

First, I build the collection by adding non-started tasks to the collection (as opposed to `.StartNew()`).  You can follow the rest.  I will ultimately create helper methods for these, but this at least shows the core code I used.

If anyone sees a more efficient way to do this, please let me know.